# Adding a header to all swagger requests

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I am currently adding swagger to an old project and I would like to add a header to all requests. 
The application has a filter that checks if your app version is high enough and thus requires the clients to send in a `version` header.

Is it possible to add this to all requests or do I have to rewrite all endpoints to have this header parameter(there is a lot of them). Would be really nice to have a global header parameter.

Should be added that I would like to do this in Java and not change the json/yaml directly

Answer (score 7):

You can add global operational parameters in your `Docket` configuration as done in last line - `.globalOperationParameters(operationParameters())`,

I am showing broader configuration but your focus for this question should be only last line.

```
@Bean
    public Docket swaggerPlugin() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .apis(Predicates.or(
            RequestHandlerSelectors
                .basePackage(....),
            RequestHandlerSelectors
                .basePackage(....)))
        .build().directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class)
        .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
        .apiInfo(apiInfo())
        .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))
        .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()))
        .globalOperationParameters(operationParameters());
    }


private List<Parameter> operationParameters() {
    List<Parameter> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    headers.add(new ParameterBuilder().name("HEADER_1")
        .description("HEADER_1 DESC")
        .modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header")
        .required(false).build());

    headers.add(new ParameterBuilder().name("HEADER_2")
        .description("HEADER_2 DESC")
        .modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header")
        .required(false).defaultValue("0").build());
    return headers;
    }
```

As illustrated, default value can also be provided. Also, these two headers will be visible on Swagger UI as text fields & values can be entered manually for each request.

Comment: hmm, is this something that is spring specific or can it be used in a "pure" java EE application?

Comment: this is springfox-swagger & Spring Boot specific. How have you included swagger for your project ?